# Spring security is blocking call to a button on a login page

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, jsf-2, csrf

Issue: I am displaying a button for change of the language on a custom login form

When user clicks on the button there should be a call to a function that changes the language, however, that is not happening because spring security is blocking other calls on that page.
Java spring security configuration that I am using is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=false)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("test000").password("test1").roles("USER").and()
    .withUser("admin000").password("test1").roles("ADMIN").and()
    .withUser("dba000").password("test1").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/login.xhtml","/resources/**","/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/views/**","/WEB-INF/template/**").authenticated()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/home.xhtml")
.and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.xhtml")
.and().httpBasic();
}
```

}

Note: When I swithch off csrf.disable() then the call to the button works, but then log in stops working.
**How should I set this up in order to have both log in and language change in place?**

JSF Login page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html" id="fview" locale="#{USManager.locale}">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>#{appMsg['application.title']}</title>
    <ui:debug />
    <f:metadata>
        <ui:insert name="metadata" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="common-style.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body style="background-image:none; background-color:#253A7C;" styleClass="LoginPage" onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="loginContainer">
                    <div class="LoginPageLogo">&nbsp;</div>

                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="#{appMsg['login.title']}" styleClass="LoginTitle" />
                        <h:form id="loginForm" method="post" prependId="false" action="/login">
                            <p:growl id="loginMessages" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" life="3000" />
                            <p:panel header="#{appMsg['login.form.header']}">
                                <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="2">
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <p:inputText id="username" size="30" />
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <h:outputText value="#{rccMsg['login.form.username']}" />
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                                    <p:message for="username"></p:message>
                                    <p:password id="password" feedback="false" size="30" />
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <h:outputText value="#{appMsg['login.form.password']}" />
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <p:spacer />
                                    <p:message for="password"></p:message>
                                    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/> -->
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{appMsg['login.form.submit']}" ajax="false" />
                                    <p:commandButton id="btnSr" value="SR" actionListener="#{USManager.useSr}" rendered="#{USManager.language=='en'}" process="@this" update="@parent">
                                        <!-- <f:setPropertyActionListener value="sr" target="#{USManager.language}"></f:setPropertyActionListener> -->
                                        <!-- <h:graphicImage name="images/flag_sr.png"/> -->
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                    <p:commandButton id="btnEn" value="EN" actionListener="#{USManager.useEn}" rendered="#{USManager.language=='sr'}" process="@this" update="@parent">
                                        <!-- <f:setPropertyActionListener value="en" target="#{USManager.language}"></f:setPropertyActionListener> -->
                                        <!-- <h:graphicImage name="images/flag_en.png"/> -->
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </h:form>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dur, 

tnx for quick response. I'm calling function useSr or useEn in USManager backing bean.These functions simple change language and print the message in console. When user clicks on the button, compiler does not call in the method. If I disable CSRF in config:
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
      .csrf().disable();
    }
}
button works fine but login does not.
How to setup above method to work for both functionalities?

Comment: URL is login.xhtml

Comment: How to add CSRF token with buttons?